# Cannot put DrawerLayout under StatusBar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, statusbar

I have an activity with a `Navigation Drawer` and using `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` I was able to put the layout under the `StatusBar` and everything worked perfectly. 
Then I decided to replace the color for the `Toolbar` and `StatusBar` with a `png` background for all the activity layout.
I run the app on the emulator (Nexus 5 with android 6.0) and the result was exactly what I wanted like you can see in **Image #1** below, but when I tried on my device (Galaxy Note 3 with android 5.0) the layout inside ScrimInsetsFrameLayout went above the `StatusBar` **Image #2**. 
I can't understand what is wrong, can you help me?

Here are my `values-v21` and my `activity.xml`

```
<style parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" name="AppTheme_Activities">

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/insetF</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/insetF</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/insetF</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

</style>



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"> <!--png image-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_activities" android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame">

        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.example.myapplication.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:insetForeground="#4000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"> .....

    </com.example.myapplication.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Image #1**
[image]

**Image #2**
[image]

Comment: what if you set the `android:fitsSystemWindows` of the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` to false ?

Comment: The DrawerLayout just doesn't extend under the statusBar

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440879/how-do-i-use-drawerlayout-to-display-over-the-actionbar-toolbar-and-under-the-st/26440880 it may help you.

Comment: I tried but nothing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

1. add to your `onCreate()` of `Activity`

   ```
       getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
               View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
   ```
2. Change `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`'s `android:fitsSystemWindows` property to `false`
3. Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `DrawerLayout`

   ```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/drawer"
       android:background="@drawable/background"> <!--png image-->

       <FrameLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent">

           <include layout="@layout/toolbar_activities" android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"/>

           <FrameLayout
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:id="@+id/content_frame">

           </FrameLayout>

       </FrameLayout>

       <com.example.myapplication.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
           android:layout_width="304dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="start"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
           app:insetForeground="#4000"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:background="#ffffff"> .....

       </com.example.myapplication.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
   ```
4. Add these styles into your `AppTheme_Activities` Theme (keeping your status desired color):

   ```
           <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
           <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
           <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
           <item name="android:statusBarColor">#4000</item>
   ```
5. This will to the state, that Toolbar gets under the StatusBar too, so you'll need to do this hack:

   - Make `Toolbar`'s height = `"wrap_content"`

     ```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
     ```
   - Set `Padding` for the `Toolbar`:

     ```
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
     ......
     ......
     public int getStatusBarHeight() {
         int result = 0;

         if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
             int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
             if (resourceId > 0) {
                 result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
             }
         }
         return result;
     }
     ```

That's should be it!

I've uploaded the source code of the test-application with Navigation Drawer below the status bar to my dropbox - [feel free to check it out.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/elnsloyozyp43u3/TranslucentStatusBarUpdated.zip?dl=0)

I have answered pretty similar question a while ago - maybe you will also find it useful: [Translucent StatusBar with dynamic ActionBar color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384963/1658267)

I hope, it helps

Comment: I did it but now I have a transparent StatusBar

Comment: @Pier and which color should it be?

Comment: I set _@color/insetF_ that is the transparent color of _app:insetForeground="_ **#4000** _"_

Comment: @Pier good news. There's a workaround for you, even if the system shadow doesn't suit you. I've added **step 1** and modified **step 4**(replaced windowTranslucentStatus with statusBarColor property). Check it out!

Comment: Nothing, the StatusBar is still transparent

Comment: @Pier double-check that windowTranslucentStatus is no longer in Styles. And that statusBarColor is set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99147/discussion-between-konstantin-loginov-and-pier).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, Pier. The annoying thing is there doesn't seem to be any decent guide on showing how to solve this issue, even though it is part of material design guidelines, etc.

Anyway, here is how I did it...

---

## Styles

My `styles.xml` contains a base theme and then my main application theme. I created another theme for my activities that use a navigation drawer like so:

```
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NavDrawer">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
</style>
```

The colour `window_background` is referencing my `colors.xml` file, which lists it as `#FFF5F5F5`. Note, the above works slightly differently for API 21+, so in the `values-v21` directory, create another `styles.xml`. This one should include the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NavDrawer">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

## Layouts

Now for the layouts. In the layout file you will have your navigation drawer in, you can include the following.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/main_adView">

            <!-- The app bar -->
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <!-- Your layout content below -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/your_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <!-- Other stuff here if you like -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <include layout="@layout/navdrawer"
        android:id="@+id/main_navigationView" />
```

Obviously you can remove the `RelativeLayout` if you don't need any other views inside it, as it would be redundant. The navigation drawer I referenced in my `<include>` tag is below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navdrawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_items" />
```

With the above code, you should have your navigation drawer correctly drawing behind the status bar.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same issue. 
I'd like to know if it is a style problem or a layout problem...when I used colors for _android:colorPrimary_ and for _android:colorPrimaryDark_ everything was great

Comment: @Pier I think if your minimum API level is set below 21 then you should use `colorPrimary` (to be compatible with older devices), but if you are just making your app for API 21+, then you can use `android:colorPrimary`. To be honest, I think overall the issue is solved by changes in both style and layouts.

Comment: I have _colorPrimary_ for _styles.xml_ in _values_ folder and _android:colorPrimaryDark_ for _styles.xml_ in _values-v21_

Comment: That should be fine - I don't think the colour values make a difference. Look at the base theme and the navigation theme particularly, as well as the Android tags used in layout files.